# Bootmgr is missing when booting with Ubuntu LiveUSB

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I downloaded 64bit Ubuntu and I put it on my USB. It is bootable, and BIOS is configured to boot from it. But when I turn on the laptop with USB in it, it says:

```
Bootmgr is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart.
```

I have windows 7 64bit installed and I want to keep it. (dual boot or something)

Device: HP PAVILION G7 1303

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in  bootable media. Make linux bootable media by unetbootin or linux live for avoiding boot problems. You are getting this message because your USB is not made bootable perfectly. By just copying files  with mounting iso not makes USB bootable.

Comment: I am able to boot windows 7  I just have problems booting and installing Ubuntu

Comment: @MatejKranjec make your USB bootable with Unetbootin.

Comment: it is bootable.

Comment: Go in bios change order of booting. Make USB Drive first in boot menu.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: I got the solution. In HP,  BIOS stops  booting  USB by prevening HDD (hard disk) data. First disable this HDD prevent option by going into BIOS settings > HDD options. After disabling that option you will not receive this message.

Comment: where is that? I opened BIOS menu and didn't found HDD options

Comment: You can ask it on Hp BIOS Forums, Since I don't use it so I am not familiar with it

Comment: where is hp bios forum and does it exist? link?

Comment: hp.com/support select your contry, choose notebook and tablets from below menu, it will ask you, product no. enter your product no given on laptop

Answer (score 0):

Try format it to ext3 or use another USB stick

Comment: But...how?


And what should I format to ext3? My usb or hard disk?

Comment: Try MultiBootISO or install Wubi and format yours USB

Comment: @Ktos While I think this *is* an answer, it would be much improved if you were to  *expand* it answer to explain how to format it ext3, as Matej Kranjec has asked. (You can at least move the information from your comment reply into the answer, but it would be even better if you gave or linked to explicit steps. Screenshots could be helpful too.)

Comment: Personally, I fail to see how using Ext3 would help. It sounds to me like the drive somehow got a Windows 6.x-like (eg Vista, Seven, Eight) bootloader installed. I would suggest you simply use [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a bootable USB drive. Reformat to FAT32 if necessary.